# Is there some way to get information about the QNetworkAccessManager queue?

Tags: qt, pyqt, queue, pyside, qnetworkaccessmanager

From the [Qt 4 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html):

> Note: `QNetworkAccessManager` queues the requests it receives.

Now, there are two things I would like to be able to do (using PyQt):

1. Check how many requests are in the `QNetworkAccessManager`'s "internal" queue, waiting to be sent.
2. Check how many requests have received an answer (i.e. count number of finished QNetworkReplies).

I assume this information must already be available to the `QNetworkAccessManager` internally, yet I have not been able to find a way to access it. I could not find anything in the Qt docs or elsewhere, but perhaps I am looking in the wrong place or using the wrong terminology.

Can someone tell me if Qt provides some way to access information about the `QNetworkAccessManager` queue?

Just for clarity: I can think of a few ways to keep track of these things myself, e.g. by checking individual QNetworkReply states, but *that's not the kind of solution I am looking for* (only as a last resort, if Qt does not provide an easier way).

--- EDIT ---

A slightly-less-than-minimal yet still trivial example of the kind of thing I had in mind:

```
import sys
import json
from PyQt4 import QtNetwork, QtGui, QtCore

def show_reply_content(reply):
    print 'url from reply content: {}'.format(
        json.loads(str(reply.readAll()))['url'])

    # Quit if all replies are finished
    reply.deleteLater()
    reply.manager().replies_unfinished -= 1
    if not reply.manager().replies_unfinished:
    app.quit()

# Some initialization
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
manager.finished.connect(show_reply_content)

# Add counter as dynamic attribute (quick and dirty)
manager.replies_unfinished = 0

# Schedule some dummy requests
number_of_requests = 10
for i in range(number_of_requests):
    manager.get(QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(
        QtCore.QUrl('http://httpbin.org/anything/{}'.format(i))))

    # Update counter
    manager.replies_unfinished += 1

# Start event loop
app.exec_()
```

In this case something like an `allFinished` signal from the manager would save me a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt does not provide a way to access the `QNetworkAccessManager` internal cache.

The `QNetworkReply` APIs provide a relatively simple way to monitor the status of replies, but that does require the user to manage the replies themselves and keep a tally of what has been requested *vs* what has been received.

The [`QNetworkAccessManager.finished()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished) signal is a fire-and-forget API that doesn't require management of the individual replies - however, there is no corresponding global signal that informs the user when *all* replies have been received.

The Qt docs are somewhat misleading with regard to the ownership of reply objects:

> **Note**: After the request has finished, it is the responsibility of the
>   user to delete the `QNetworkReply` object at an appropriate time.

This gives the impression that Qt does not maintain ownership of the replies, but in fact the `QNetworkAccessManager` makes itself parent of all its repiles, so that is not the case.

Given that all replies have their manager as parent, there is a relatively simple solution available in PyQt for checking the status of all current replies. The slot connected to the manager's `finished()` signal could contain code like this:

```
def handle_finished(self, reply):
    data = reply.readAll()
    # do something with data...
    reply.deleteLater()
    if all(child.isFinished() for child in
           reply.manager().findChildren(QtNetwork.QNetworkReply)):
        print('all finished')
```